# How to find which clusters a particular gene is expressed in using scanpy for scRNA-seq?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics, scanpy

I am using scanpy to cluster and label my scRNA seq data. I have several genes of interest and would like to identify from which cluster they are expressed from. When I run:

```
adata.var[adata.var_names == 'LINC01138:23']
```

I get a table with the gene id, n_cells_by_counts and total_counts amongst other columns. In the total_counts, there are 82 cells that express the LINC01138:23. I am trying to find out which cells the LINC01138:23 gene is expressed in, but since the cluster data is in adata.obs, I am unsure how to find this data.

The genes I have are not highly expressed, so I cannot find it when I run

```
markers[markers.names == 'LINC01138:23']
```

I have tried subsetting my data depending on which clusters I think they belong to, but the total_counts does not change even though I am sure they appear in other clusters than the ones I subsetted.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a dot plot to see what fraction of cells from each cluster are expressing that gene. Use something like this `sc.pl.dotplot(adata, ['LINC01138:23'], groupby='leiden')`. See [the tutorial](https://scanpy-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pbmc3k.html) for more plots that can help.